# The Draw2D touch project still running

Tags: draw2d-js

I am looking for HTML5/2D/Javascript library to use in a project, where I need to manipulate shapes and connectos.

The **Draw2D** seems to be quite good, but after seen the last change log was in 2016 I got a little worried about the future of the library.

*Some one knows if the project still running?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it has been quiet for sometime but the project owner have created couple other projects related to the draw2d. So I don't think it's end of life.

In fact, we are still using draw2d heavily in our products and planning to create more applications centered around draw2d capabilities. The library has been working great with ExtJs.

Comment: Joe thanks for your insight. I will take my changes and use it in the project, I wish the project owner continue the tool development.